# Cannot Find Symbol when compiling a java code

Tags: java, antlr, antlr3

Compiling this using cmd : javac Test.java. However compilation fails, saying it cant find symbol parser.prog(). Any ideas?

```
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

    public class TestT {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            // Create an TLexer that feeds from that stream
            //TLexer lexer = new TLexer(new ANTLRInputStream(System.in));
            TLexer lexer = new TLexer(new ANTLRFileStream("input.txt"));

            // Create a stream of tokens fed by the lexer
            CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);

            // Create a parser that feeds off the token stream
            TParser parser = new TParser(tokens);

            // Begin parsing at rule prog
            parser.prog();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post a link to the documentation/code of ```TParser```.

Comment: Here it is : https://www.codepile.net/pile/lgAYRNgK

Comment: Please note that antlr generated this parser. Writing the grammar is all I did.

Comment: I cannot find the method ```prog()``` in there. I cannot find it in [Parser](https://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/Parser.html) or [Recognizer](https://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/Recognizer.html), too. Have a look in [here](https://www.antlr.org/api/Java/index.html), maybe you'll find the solution.

Comment: What is the method used then to generate the parser? Any idea? @akuzminykh

Comment: Please share the entire error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `T.g4` grammar (or `T.g`), you must also have a parser rule named `prog`:

```
grammar T;

prog
 : ...
 ;

...
```

Looking at your generated parser, I see you have a parser rule like this:

```
filter
 : expression EOF
 ;
```

Use that instead:

```java
// Begin parsing at rule prog
parser.filter();
```